# Webservice initialisation issue

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a simple web service. When I call my test method for the first time it takes about 5 seconds to respond and thereafter it takes very less time which is fine.

But if my application stays idel for 5 mins and when i call the same method again it takes same amount of time took before to respond. How can I make it faster ?

I tried by setting the keepalive = true and pre compiling and deploying, still no luck

```
localhost.WebService1 svc = new WebSvcTest.localhost.WebService1();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

            Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch.Start();

            string returnVal = svc.HelloWorld();

            stopWatch.Stop();

            TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

            // Format and display the TimeSpan value.
            string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
                ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
                ts.Milliseconds / 10);

            MessageBox.Show(elapsedTime);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem was IIS ProcessModel IdleTimeout was set to 20 mins. I set it to 0, now everything works fine. thanks a lot