# Web Service Singleton object problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am creating a singleton object in the first request to the web service and keeping it in the memory.

This works fine for first few seconds. If I make a request 5 minutes later, I can see that the singleton object is created again? is my singleton object getting disposed after x no of minutes ?

how can i make increase the life-time of my object forever ?

```
    public sealed class Singleton
    {
        static ServerInstance instance = null;
        static readonly object padlock = new object();

        Singleton() {
        }

        public static ServerInstance Instance {
            get {
                lock (padlock) {
                    if (instance == null) {
                        instance = new ServerInstance();
                    }
                    return instance;
                }
            }
        }
        ~Singleton()
        {
          #if DEBUG
                  ExceptionFactory.Fatal("~Singleton() called!");
          #endif
        }
    }


    [WebMethod]
    public string OnReceiveEvent(string objectXmlData, string objectType) {

        if (!Singleton.Instance.initServerComplete) {
            InitServer();
        }

       return Singleton.Instance.OnReceiveEvent(objectXmlData, objectType);
    }


 public void InitServer() {
            if (!Singleton.Instance.initServerComplete) {
                Singleton.Instance.InitServer();
                Singleton.Instance.initServerComplete = true;

                GC.KeepAlive(Singleton.Instance);
            }
        }
```

Comment: i tried this GC.KeepAlive(Singleton.Instance); as well, but no luck

Comment: possible duplicate of [Webservice initialisation issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323211/webservice-initialisation-issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there can be no of reasons but mostly i am thinking about ASPNET process recyling.

Comment: Deleting my post as with the update to the question, this would be my first suspicion too.

Comment: problem was IIS ProcessModel IdleTimeout was set to 20 mins.  I set it to 0, now everything works fine. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try to derive from [`MarshalByRefObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.marshalbyrefobject.aspx) and override [`InitializeLifetimeService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.marshalbyrefobject.initializelifetimeservice.aspx):

```
public override Object InitializeLifetimeService()
{
  ILease lease = (ILease)base.InitializeLifetimeService();
  if (lease.CurrentState == LeaseState.Initial)
  {
     lease.InitialLeaseTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(100);
     lease.SponsorshipTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(100);
     lease.RenewOnCallTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100);
  }
  return lease;
}
```

Read more about [`LifetimeServices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/99scak7e.aspx).